# Validate field in entity without validating in parameter

Tags: java, spring, validation, asp.net-web-api

I have an entity object similar to the following

```
@Document(collection = "job")
public class Job {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private JobStatus status;

    @NotBlank
    private String term;

    ...standard getters/setters
}
```

I have a controller something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Job> createJob(@RequestBody @Valid Job job) {
    ...store the new job in the database
}
```

The Job.status property is set by the code before storing to the database. Any "status" property included in the request body to the createJob method is ignored.

I would like to validate that Job.status is not null when the job is written to the database, but users must not be required to include a status in the request body. If I annotate the Job.status property with @NotNull, the validation of the request body fails unless I include "status".

How do I validate the status field only when persisting to data store and not as part of the request body?

Comment: If I get it well, you want to use ´@NotNull´ but ignore the ´@Valid´ annotation in the controller if the status field is null? Are you using hasErrors on the controller?

Comment: I do not wish to ignore the `@Valid` annotation in the controller because it also validates the value of the term field.I want the `@NotNull` annotation to apply to the database validation, but not the controller parameter validation.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the database entity as a UI entity with different validation rules. You have options:

- Use different classes for the UI and the DB
- Create a custom JSR-303 validator for your not null which you somehow avoid applying when you validate in the UI layer
- Put the constraint for not null in the database itself, rather than hibernate/JPA and handle the constraint exception